# How to send email with gzipped body in Java

Tags: java, email, base64, gzip

I have to send some lengthy plain text email messages and I was wondering if I could compress the email body using something like `Content-Encoding: gzip` (like web servers do) and possibly `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. I would avoid attachments, so that the recipient could see the message as if it were uncompressed. The text to send is highly redundant, therefore the compression ratio would be high. Thanks.